# #define EDB_REC (byte*)(void*)&

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, arduino-due

I'm programming on an Arduino Due using the Extended Database Library and encountered the following line in the example.

```
EDB_Status result = db.updateRec(1, EDB_REC logEvent);
```

I do not understand the `EDB_REC logEvent` part. What does EDB_REC do? (logEvent is just a struct)
So I went to EDB_REC's implementation and got:

```
#define EDB_REC (byte*)(void*)&
```

which confuses me more because I have never seen such a #define statement.

Can someone explain me how those 2 code lines work? Searching on google I get only entries on how to define constants and simple functions with #define

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that macros are just replaced in the source as a separate step before the compilers parser starts parsing the code.

That means `db.updateRec(1, EDB_REC logEvent);` will after macro expansion be seen by the compiler parser as `db.updateRec(1, (byte*)(void*)& logEvent);`

Comment: Huh, that makes sense. Still, what would the '(byte*)(void*)&' part do on logEvent?

Comment: @AlexanderFandosJahrsetz The `&` is the address-of operator. With `&logEvent` you get a pointer to the variable. The `(void*)` cast that pointer to a generic untyped pointer, and `(byte*)` then further cast that to a pointer to `byte`.

Comment: Remember: its always RIGHT to LEFT.